# Adjustments on brake pedal

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, brake-pedal

My brake pedal has a 1/2 inch to  3/4 inch play left to right when I am using it. Is there an adjustment to remove the slack from it? Its a 2004 Chevy Silverado 1500 with 5.3 liter.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at my Silvy, but would bet there are bushings at the top of the brake pedal arm which controls this movement. Take a look and see if they're worn out (or even non-existent at this point). Replacing these should firm the pedal back into its correct alignment and travel directions.